# Can't prevent double entry c# listview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, duplicates

i'm trying to code a task manager.

Here my problem i add the process list in a listview but
i can't find a way out to not having same double entry

here the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Process_Manager
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<int> processId = new List<int>();
        int first_time = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void do_job(List<int> test,int id)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < test.Count; i++)
            {
                if(!listView1.Items.ContainsKey(Convert.ToString(id)))
                {
                    ListViewItem t = new ListViewItem(Convert.ToString(id));
                    listView1.Items.Add(t);
                }
            }
        }

        private void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] process = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process t in process)
            {
                processId.Add(t.Id);
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < processId.Count; i++)
            {
                ListViewItem listviewitemprocess = new ListViewItem(Convert.ToString(processId[i]));
                listView1.Items.Add(listviewitemprocess);
            }
            processId.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

I'v tried to use a list, add data to list then clear the list for having a fresh list without doublon.
But this sees to not work !

I'm really stuck !

Comment: Where is do_job called from?

Comment: Is the problem that every time `listView1` is clicked the current process IDs get added to those already in the list?  You should be clearing `listView1` on each invocation of `listView1_MouseUp()`; `processId` can then be made a local variable or, even better, eliminated and just populate `listView1` inside your `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I see some steps where you're adding items to the listview but never removing any. I'd recommend making a method just for updating the listview with the current collection and I recommend calling listView1.Items.Clear(); before adding the collection.

Something like this perhaps:

```
using System.Linq;

private void UpdateListView()
{ 
    var newListViewItems =
        Process.GetProcesses().
            Select(p => new ListViewItem(p.Id.ToString())).
            ToArray();
    listView1.BeginUpdate();
    try
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        listView1.Items.AddRange(newListViewItems);
    }
    finally
    {
        listView1.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```